# unable to access variable in onclick method

Tags: android, int, onclicklistener

I'm setting up an onclick method and i cannot access an int that i have set up in its parent method, is there a different way to use the Int?

here is the code:

```
Date past = new Date(cYear, cMonth, cDay); // current Date
    Date today = new Date(mYear, mMonth, mDay); // date Choosen by the user
    int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays()+1;
    mDateDisplay.setText(""+days);
    // display the current date (this method is below)
   updateDisplay();

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               s = WorkoutChoice.this.weight.getText().toString();
               s2 = WorkoutChoice.this.height.getText().toString();
               int w = Integer.parseInt(s);
               double h = Double.parseDouble(s2);
               double BMI = (w/h)/h;
               t.setText(""+BMI);
               id = db.insertTitle("001", ""+days, ""+BMI)
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it the 'days' int? Make it final: 'final int days = ....'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to refer the variable from an inner class, you need to make the variable `final`:

```
final int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays()+1;
```

Comment: thank you that helped. i thought it was something stupid that i was missing