# MediaPLayer not stopping

Tags: audio, android-mediaplayer

I dont understand how to actually get this to work. My code is;

```
package com.example.user.medialert;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by User' on 9/24/2016.
 */
public class alert extends Activity {

final MediaPlayer Siren = new MediaPlayer() ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert);
    MediaPlayer Siren = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alertsiren);
    try {
        Siren.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Siren.start();

}


public void onClickOk1(View view) {
    Siren.stop();


    Intent intent = new Intent(alert.this, counter.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

The onClick changes the activity as it is supposed to however when I add the     Siren.Stop(); code, 'Siren' is invalid, the error being cannot resolve symbol.
I have tried

```
MediaPlayer Siren = new MediaPlayer();
```

above the onCreate method, allowing siren to be used in the onClick, but it still doesn't stop playing the sound.
Any ideas?
EDIT 
Added to show the code I have updated attempting to make final, and this now crashes the app. 
Highlighting Siren under the onCreate method shows that the program isn't linking the Siren in the Siren.stop(); call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to access variable in onclick method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960215/unable-to-access-variable-in-onclick-method). Definitely need to move the variable outside of `onCreate()` to access it in other methods. Make sure you are only instantiating a single `Siren` objet. Plus, try adding `final`.

Comment: As mentioned, I did also move the variable to before the on create method and it did not help. I will try and add final to the object to see it that helps.

Comment: Adding final to the media player call, before onCreate causes the app the crash :(